# Simple Stopwatch in python using time.sleep

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a simple stopwatch using counter logic and sleep function in python. It seems to increment fine and be pretty accurate with the one issue of my if statement.

```
self.sec = 0
self.min = 0

time.sleep(1)
self.sec = self.sec + 1
if (self.sec == 59):
    self.sec = 0
    self.min = self.min + 1
```

I'd like minutes to increment whenever seconds reach 59 as shown. Only problem is for a quick second these two things happen at the same time and reads the wrong time. For example, after 59 seconds it reads 1:59 and then reverts back to 1.1 and continues as normal.

Comment: Where are you displaying the counter or printing the seconds and the minute. More than logic it could be a print or display UI issue. Please share the rest of the code as well.

Comment: FWIW, this isn't how to make an accurate stopwatch. You should simply store a start timestamp, and on every tick take the difference from that start timestamp to the current time. Then format that as h:m:s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing: Weird, that your minute would only have 59 seconds instead of 60. Your example would result in the exact behavior described in your problem. Try changing to `if (self.sec == 60): ...` and check the results.

Comment: I had 60 in the beginning and it was giving me other problems that seemed to be fixed when I went to 59. I guess it just needed to be changed back when I changed my logic. Thank you! This worked